# Como aplicar "Modularidad" en código fuente

Tags: c

Hola estoy empezando a programar en C. Mi pregunta es si se puede separar las funciones de un archivo aparte y luego llamar a esas funciones haciendo un #include.

Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// La funcion que quiero separar en un archivo aparte.
int calcular(int a, int b){
  int total = a + b;
  return total;
}


 int main()
 {
  int all = calcular(2,3);
  printf("%i", all);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrias separar tus funciones de la siguiente manera.

### libreria.c

```
/**
  * Aca definimos los procedimientos que realizaran las funciones
  */
#include "libreria.h"

int calcular(int a, int b){
  int total = a + b;
  return total;
}
```

### libreria.h

```
/**
  * Aca realizamos la definicion de las funciones que tendremos en nuestro programa
  */
#ifndef LIBRERIA_H
#define LIBRERIA_H 1

int calcular(int a, int b);

#endif
```

### main.c

```
/**
  * Aqui llamamos a las funciones
  */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libreria.h"

int main()
{
  int all = calcular(2,3);
  printf("%i", all);
}
```

Para compilar basta hacer lo siguiente:

```
gcc libreria.c -c -o libreria.o
gcc main.c -c -o main.o
gcc main.o libreria.o -o programa
```

Resultado de la operacion:

```
./programa
```

> 5